# An alternative to block eval?

Tags: perl, try-catch, eval, die

Is there an equivalent of the following -

```
eval { die "reason 1"; }; warn $@ if $@;
eval { die "reason 2"; }; warn $@ if $@;
eval { die "reason 3"; }; warn $@ if $@;
.
.
```

As you can notice, the following code wont print out every possible reasons for the script to die..

```
eval {
    die "reason 1";
    die "reason 2";
    die "reason 3";
};
warn $@ if $@;
```

[EDIT] I would like to know all possible reasons the script (that uses lot many libraries) can fail. The die statements are not in a place i can edit.

Comment: Don't you just want `warn`? Or do you want to test out failure modes from a library? Reading the source could work better there. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The latter. I would like to know all possible reasons the script (that uses lot many libraries) can fail. The die statements are not in a place i can edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

overriding die is not exactly an alternative to eval, but this is what I think you're asking about, trapping die and turning it into a warn, log die and resume/continue program

```
$ perl -e " eval{die 1;}; die 2; die 3; "
2 at -e line 1.

$ perl -Mwarnerous  -e " eval{die 1;}; die 2; die 3; "
FAKE die : 2 at -e line 1
FAKE die : 3 at -e line 1

$ cat warnerous.pm
*CORE::GLOBAL::die = sub {
    unless( $^S ){
        warn( qq{FAKE die : @_ @{[sprintf q{at %s line %s },(caller)[1,2] ]}\n} );
    }
};
1;
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for, thank you !! There are places where this wont work though - Some libraries use Internals::SvREADONLY that cause the script to die. But that is out of scope for this question, as it will involve me digging into the unknown realm of perl Internals' modules..

Comment: Also, while you are here, can you explain why we need <code>unless ($^S)</code>. I read through its meaning here - http://www.catonmat.net/download/perl.predefined.variables.pdf - does it mean this will skip dies inside evals ??

Comment: It will skip warning for die-s inside evals -- its useful to know in case you might need it

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
my $problems;
for my $r (1 .. 3) {
    eval { die "reason $r"; 1 } or $problems .= $@;
}

warn "There were the following problems:\n$problems";
```

Comment: Hi, I'd like to find out various reasons a script could fail.. And no, this is not what i'm looking for. I'll probably update the question to reflect this !

Comment: @trinity: It has nothing to do with your question. It should work as well.